# Mechanize - Receiving Errno::EMFILE: Too many open files - socket(2) after a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mechanize

I'm running an application that uses mechanize to fetch some data every so often from an RSS feed.

It runs as a heroku worker and after a day or so I'm receiving the following error:
Errno::EMFILE: Too many open files - socket(2)

I wasn't able to find a "close" method within mechanize, is there anything special I need to be doing in order to close out my browser sessions?

Here is how I create the browser + read information:

```
  def mechanize_browser
    @mechanize_browser ||= begin
      agent = Mechanize.new
      agent.redirect_ok = true
      agent.request_headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding' => "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        'Accept-Language' => "en-US,en;q=0.8",
      }
      agent
    end
  end
```

And actually fetching information:

```
  response = mechanize_browser.get(url)
```

And then closing after the response:

```
  def close_mechanize_browser
    @mechanize_browser = nil
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck with this so far? The solution I provided below is a bit of a shift away from your existing code – from an abstracted function to a built-in one – but should accomplish precisely what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 6):

Since you manually can't close each instance of `Mechanize`, you can try invoking `Mechanize` as a block. According to [the docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize#start-class_method):

> After the block executes, the instance is cleaned up. This includes closing all open connections.

So, rather than abstracting `Mechanize.new` into a custom function, try running `Mechanize` via the `start` class method, which should automatically close all your connections upon completion of the request:

```
Mechanize.start do |m|
  m.get("http://example.com")
end
```

Comment: Will try this out soon - thanks so much, I totally over looked this!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. The Mechanize start example by @zeantsoi is the answer that I ended up following, but there is also a `Mechanize.shutdown` method if you want to do this manually without their block.

There is also an option that you can add a lambda on post_connect_hooks
`Mechanize.new.post_connect_looks << lambda {|agent, url, response, response_body| agent.shutdown }`